# Object is undefined Yet console.log Shows an Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

this is so bizarre.  it logs a db object but db.media.update seems to never return, I can't put a debug point anywhere and when I puta debug point on that line, db shows undefined

here's a screencast showing the problem https://youtu.be/JXyuUbscPLQ

**index.js**

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

import Sequelize from 'sequelize'

import AppConfig from './../../config'

const basename = path.basename(__filename)
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'develop'
const config = AppConfig.get('/db')
const db = {}
let sequelize

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env[config.use_env_variable],
    config
  )
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    config
  )
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file))
    db[model.name] = model
  })

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db)
  }
})

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize
db.env = env

export default db
```

**mediaGateway.js**

```
import db from './../../db/models/index'

const mediaGateway = {
  update: async (media) => {
    const updatedMedia = await db.media.update(media, { where: { uuid: media.uuid } })
    return updatedMedia
  }
}

export default mediaGateway
```

[image]

and here's what console log outputs, a db object.  I know it's a db object because I also console.logged db.media, etc

[image]

[image]

Comment: `update(values: Object, options: Object): Promise<Array<affectedCount, affectedRows>>`  promise does not return updated media, it returns array.

Comment: the problem isn't what it's returning, the problem is db is undefined!  But yet it console.logs an object for db!  And...it doesn't seem to return and hit the next console.log...and no errors are reported

Comment: can You declare contents of `./../../db/models/index'` ?

Comment: sure updating to include that now

Comment: also added a screencast url

Comment: ok, reading... wait

Comment: I hate sequelize

Comment: but I like sequelize, it's not sequelize issue to be hated (:

Comment: probably user error but I don't see what that could possibly be yet :)

Comment: still don't get why I lost the db instance in mine but not @num8er 's class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In fact Your code seems ok.

Let's try different approach as injecting db object in class constructor:

```
import db from './../../db/models/index'

class MediaGateway 
{
  constructor (db) {
    this._db = db;
  }

  async update (media) {
    const db = this._db;
    return await db.media.update(media, { where: { uuid: media.uuid } });
  }
}

export default new MediaGateway(db);
```

If it does not help, so try to debug db object inside of module before exporting:

```
console.log('Before exporting:', db, db.media);
export default db;
```

If it shows ok, but still You cannot get db object in another file so try use old plain:

```
module.exports = db;
```

and

```
const db = require('./../../db/models');
```

Me personally still not using ES6 export/import, async/await features until it becomes mature. I still use promises and old-school way of exporting and requiring modules.

Comment: same behavior....no luck.  Watch my screencast too if you haven't already, I put a link to it above.  It just makes asbolute no sense that console.log logs a db object, yet my IDE shows it's undefined during the call, but it's hitting sequelize, but yet it's a black hole and I don't know what happened with sequelize when it appeared to have had my where clause

Comment: check my updated answer, try to do console.log before exporting and launch Your code, see if there race condition that calls db object before it has being loaded or initialized

Comment: I've done that too, console.log inside index.js returns a valid db object

Comment: @PositiveGuy can You do `module.exports = db;` inside of module and in another file: `const db = require('./../../db/models');`  ?

Comment: yes yours worked...is it that I somehow lose the db reference inside my arrow function?

Comment: maybe it's something to do with the fact that the arrow function has its own scope and that it's set as a literal prop?

Comment: it's not arrow function issue, it's about export/import vs module.export/require

Comment: hmm but import.js is exporting it using es6 export not node and I'm importing it not requiring it in my gateway

Comment: actually I have no clue, cuz ideally Your code should work, but practically it shows that it's not.

Comment: `console.log` can have a small `1` beside it in Chrome console. Hover over that, and it'll say, `evaluated just now` which means when `console.log` was called, the variable was undefined, but, later became defined and that's what's shown

Comment: I am running this from an integration test.  I don't use chrome tools, I use WebStorm.  I don't debug everything in a browser, that's too manual.